# Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/category/[...Id]' in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I faced build time error, **Error: getStaticPaths is required for dynamic SSG pages and is missing for '/category/[...Id]'**, How can I use getStaticPaths in my code refered https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-getstaticpaths-value this but how to call path in my function, Could you solve my issue please

Code
[...Id].js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { Grid, Image,Segment, Card } from "semantic-ui-react" 
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import Layout from '../../components/layout'


const Post = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { Id } = router.query
  console.log(props.category_list)  
  return(
    <>
    <Layout>
    <Head>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
            {/* <meta name="description" content={seo_description} /> */}
            <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
            <meta name="google-site-verification" content="rtIRrUNRpgZ_lFtlfS8LJ0-8j_d569BXS9NOGa_nM6Y" />
           
          </Head>  
      <Grid className="store-list">
        <Grid.Column width={16}>
          <p>
            <span>{props.category_title.heading_label}</span>
          </p>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
      <Grid columns={4} className="all-offers storeList">
        {props.category_list.map((x) => {
          return (
            <Grid.Column>
              <Segment>
                <Card>
                  <a href  ={x.store_url}>
                    {" "}
                    <Image
                      src={x.image}
                      alt=""
                      className="collection-img"
                    ></Image>
                  </a>
                  <Card.Content>
                    <a href  ={x.store_url}>
                      {" "}
                      <Card.Header>{x.name}</Card.Header>
                    </a>
                    <Card.Description>{x.store_summary}</Card.Description>
                  </Card.Content>
                  <Card.Content extra>
                    <p className="rewards">
                      <span>
                        <img src="/images/rewards.png" alt=""></img>
                      </span>
                      Cash rewards upto <span>AED {x.cashback}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p className="location">
                      <span>
                        <img src="/images/location.png" alt=""></img>
                      </span>
                      <span className="store-location" key="index">{x.store_branches}</span>
                      {/* {x.store_branches.map((locations, index) => (
                        <span className="store-location">
                          {index === 0 ? (
                            <span>{locations.store_location}</span>
                          ) : index >= 1 ? (
                            <span>
                              ,&nbsp;&nbsp;{locations.store_location}
                            </span>
                          ) : null}
                        </span>
                      ))} */}
                    </p>
                  </Card.Content>
                </Card>
              </Segment>
            </Grid.Column>
          );
        })}
      </Grid> 
      </Layout>
    </>

  )
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.Id[1];
  const postBody = {
    category_id: id,
    offer_type: "",
  };
  const offerList = await fetch('https://le.app.ae/api/v5/web/list',{
    method:'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  })
  const category = await offerList.json();
    // const bookJson = JSON.stringify(book)
    // const bookJson=offerData.stores;
  const category_list=category.stores;
  const category_title=category;
  return {
    props: {
      category_list,
      category_title
    }
  };
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: my category link is http://localhost:3000/category/26

Comment: Could you please help me any one.

Answer (score 0):

will try to help you!

With `getStaticProps` you **need (obliged)** to use `getStaticPath` ([link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#example))

After your code in `getStaticProps` add `getStaticPaths` function. **!IMPORTANT!** you write your `getStaticPaths` only after `getStaticProps` function, otherwise it can trigger some error

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
// change your API url to get ALL categories
const res = await fetch(process.env.APIpath + '/api/public/getCategories')
const posts = await res.json()

// Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts, play with params variable you are returning
const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
  params: { id: post._id },
}))

// We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
// { fallback: blocking } will server-render pages
// on-demand if the path doesn't exist.
return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

For the `fallback`, you can check this [post](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation), to check the differences between possible values.

So, file need to have next hierarchy of functions:

1. `Const Post`
2. `async function getStaticProps()`
3. `async function getStaticPaths()`

Comment: Thanks how to pass two param in this params: { id: post._id , name: post.name}, is correct

Comment: Didn't understand your question, does my code work? You separating your values by ','
params: { id: post._id, name: post.name },

Comment: I want to pass two parameter inside of  path, this is my url http://localhost:3000/store/shaandaar-restaurant/149, have two values "shaandaar-restaurant" and 149

Comment: Can't really help you with this type of question, you need to test the code and console.log() variables to check which type of data it returns.